# Replacing numers by its reciprocal when its greater than a certain value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of values in mathematica, for example num= {1,3,4,5}.  How do I change the elements by its reciprocal if they are greater than a certain number, otherwise replace ed by zero. For example, if the a number is greater than 2 then i wish to take reciprocal of number, other wise replace it with zero. num= {0,1/3,1/4,1/5}

Answer (score 2):

Let's say our list is defined like this :

```
mylist = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

We simply define a new function that does what you want:

```
ReciprocalReplace[x_]:=If[ x!=0 , 1/x , 0 ]
```

That returns the inverse of a number if its nonzero and returns '0' for '0'.
Now we can either use `Map[]` to apply the function on the list or make the function applicable on lists by "SetAttribute"

**The first Strategy using `Map[]`:**

```
Map[ReciprocalReplace, mylist]
```

that returns:

```
{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5}
```

we could also use this shorthand, equivalent notation:

```
ReciprocalReplace /@ mylist
```

**The second Strategy using `SetAttribute[function,Listable]:`**
In this way, first we should tell Mathematica that this our function can be applied on lists:

```
SetAttributes[ReciprocalReplace, Listable]
```

Now we can apply our function on any list and it would work just fine:

```
ReciprocalReplace[mylist]
```

that again returns:

```
{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num= {1,3,4,5}; 
Cases[num, s_:> If[s>2, 1/s, 0], Infinity]

{0, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}
```